# Android - Display bitmaps in imageView one by one in scrollview

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I want to display my bitmaps in one `imageview` one by one with a kind of `scrollview` that when you scroll it the image slide to the next image without "transition".

I have an example on this link but you need to login:
https://app.figure1.com/image/0/561f0cd3058ea7204ff5334a

**EDIT 1:**
For those who don't want or can't click on the link, the indicator I want is that of the `input type=range` of html.

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with a ViewPager and a ViewPagerIndicator, here is some example:
 http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/

Comment: Thanks for your answer ; but with viewpager there are transitions between 2 images and the indicator does not look like what I want. Please click on link for see exactly what I mean (unfortunately, you need to login :/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `PhotoView` Library (https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) with a `ViewPager` 
You can check our the `PhotoView` Library's Sample (https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/photoview/sample/ViewPagerActivity.java) 
It's already done there.

I hope this helps.